# How do I install flash in to Firefox running with Wine?

Tags: 11.10, wine, flash, winetricks

I'm using a website called busuu.com, which also let you chat and video chat, but you need Adobe Flash to do so.

I have Ubuntu and I have also Chromiun and I have installed flash, but will not let me use the camera.

I have decided to use Firefox with wine to see if it would work but did not, I could not install flash in to it.

What can I do about this?

my webcam works fine in ubuntu, i have cheese and I take pictures. but im thinking that the problem is the webpage beacause is there where the cam doesn;t work at all. I'm going to try in other webpage. my computer is a dell inpiron mini 10-12. my webcam the original 0.3 megapixels.I have Ubuntu 11.10

---

*(original from user)*

my problema es el siguiente: Soy usuario de una pagina web llamada busuu.com, donde permiten chatear y tambien videochat, pero hay que tener adobe flash para poder hacerlo. en ubuntu tengo chromiun y tengo tambien adobe flash, pero no me permite usar la camara. decidi utilizar firefox con wine con la esperanza de poder hacerlo, pero no tiene el adobe flash plash, he tratado de instalarlo pero no puedo. que debo hacer?

Comment: Hola, Ask Ubuntu da soporte en Inglés para preguntas formuladas en Inglés en el site. Voy a traducir esto para ti pero la próxima vez por favor haga sus preguntas en Inglés.

Comment: Just wanted to commend Bruno for being helpful and going to the extra length of translating the question. This is much friendlier than just chastising the user for not using english, as I've seen in some questions. Thanks!

Comment: Alfredo, please give more information about your camera. Hardware support for Wine applications goes through Ubuntu, so if the camera doesn't work in Ubuntu, I think it will also not work on Wine.

Comment: Does your camera work with Ubuntu? If you use `cheese` or similar can you verify that the camera is working?

Comment: I run Ubuntu with firefox installed and with Adobe 11,2,202,197 installed. Works fine here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Step 1

Use this link and download the latest version of flash player for windows.(select windows 7 as your OS) - [DOWNLOAD](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/)

- Step 2

Now you will get a .exe file and open it with wine to provide flash support to the web browsers you installed inside wine.

**This may be the answer for your primary question. But not sure whether your web cam problem will be solved by this**

Comment: download 32bit version

Comment: doesn't work on newest version

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be using [Winetricks](https://code.google.com/p/winetricks/).

Flash 11:

```
winetricks flash11
```

Flash 10:

```
winetricks flash
```

Those commands should automatically download Flash from Adobe and install it into Wine.

If `winetricks` is not there, you'll have to install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

According to [this winetricks bug](https://code.google.com/p/winetricks/issues/detail?id=155) Firefox might crash after installing flash11, which can be solved by running `winetricks vcrun2005`.

*Important*: I posted this answer in case it's useful for someone, but the method doesn't seem to be working right now. `winetricks flash11` fails with a "file not found" error, and `winetricks flash` downloads the installer and then fails with a checksum error (I have winetricks version 20120912, installed from 12.04 repos).

Comment: for me `winetricks flash` installed v14, the latest...

Comment: What is the benefit of installing flash via winetricks, compared to simply running `wine install_flash_player.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

It is not answer to the question but, why don't you try to change your flash global settings in this site: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html

It is not a screenshot or a mockup. This will change your settings.

Find the site you're looking for and allow it to access the webcam. Should work without using Firefox through wine.

Answer (score 0):

I have the easiest method to get done what you want.  I switched a long time ago to the offical version of Google Chrome instead of Chromium or Firefox because it comes bundled with its own version of Adobe Flash.  That means it works perfectly.

So just go to this link and download it - https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/

I haven't ran into anything I couldn't run since and never need to worry about installing flash or switching versions or messing with Wine.

Answer (score 0):

winetricks's flash11 is broken, version, checksums and names changed. just replace by this

```
w_metadata flash11 dlls \
    title="Flash Player 11" \
    publisher="Adobe" \
    year="2011" \
    media="download" \
    file1="install_flash_player.exe" \
    file2="install_flash_player_ax.exe" \
    installed_file1="$W_SYSTEM32_DLLS_WIN/Macromed/Flash/FlashUtil32_11_5_502_135_Plugin.exe" \
    installed_file2="$W_SYSTEM32_DLLS_WIN/Macromed/Flash/FlashUtil32_11_5_502_135_ActiveX.exe" \
    homepage="http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/"

load_flash11()
{
    # Active X plugin
    # 2011-11-12: sha1sum 8314061c4d73c9957dfb4da525d77437ee6abf0e
    w_download http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/11.5.502.135/install_flash_player_ax.exe 2a0571dc3d8b28b62586beb1bffd0c5eca3743cc
    cd "$W_CACHE"/flash11

    w_try $WINE install_flash_player_ax.exe ${W_OPT_UNATTENDED:+ /install}

    # Mozilla / Firefox plugin
    # 2011-11-12: sha1sum f1f76c35564c9f842a7e005d97f5008173466d46
    w_download http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/11.5.502.135/install_flash_player.exe 6c0d910858ba04223da2bfbdd069ef7f6e0f0894

    w_try $WINE install_flash_player.exe ${W_OPT_UNATTENDED:+ /install
}
```