# My struggle with Adobe Flash EXE files as a new Ubuntu User

Tags: wine, firefox, flash

Okay, I'm new to using Ubuntu, but the only real problem I'm having, is not being able to open certain **.exe** files (while having **WINE**), due to **Adobe Flash** not being able to load. I have **Adobe Flash** player, for **FireFox**. If anyone could give me a tip or two as to how to open said executables that require flash player, it would be a great help.

Sincerely, ***~Permanently Banned~***

Comment: How did you install adobe flash player?Also tell the output of  'dpkg --status flashplugin-installer' and 'dpkg --status adobe-flashplugin'

Comment: Have you checked if the .exe you want to run has a Linux equivalent application? I have in the past bypassed such executable (which was just a custom menu application) that wanted flash player installed, by finding out the data folder containing the flash/swf files and playing them in Google Chrome (which has a native flash player) or using Gnash SWF Player, which can be installed from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: if it's just a video, `vlc` plays many flash videos too

Answer (score 0):

This is my new, applicable, answer.  The old answer pertained entirely to difficulties running wine.  This new answer pertains to the actual problem.

The problem you are having centers entirely on a misconception you appear to have that to install anything under Ubuntu you should be using .exe files.  You should not.  files ending in .exe are for windows and DOS and have only particular uses in Ubuntu such as making programs like microsoft word run under Ubuntu (which is easy using winetricks), but I digress.

For what you are trying to do you should not use anything ending in .exe  If you are, you will only end in failure.  For several months, certain youtube files requiring flash have been having difficulty running under Ubuntu, and several of us have tried various solutions, up to and even including installing firefox for windows under Ubuntu.  I did it, and it didn't solve the problem.  What did work for me was to install the Google Chrome Browser, but in no way am I suggesting that's the only solution.

**Installing Chrome -detail:**
To install the version of chrome which successfully opens flash videos without difficulty, please open [this link](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/) and follow the instructions.  Please note, it will pop you back to the Ubuntu Software Center which IMO you ought to be using instead but sadly does not otherwise support this version of chrome at the moment.

**Standalone flash player:**
In your most recent comment (at this moment) you seemed to indicate you wanted a standalone flash player.  [This one](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lucid/gnash/) is the best I can do at this moment.  I do not believe that installing one made for windows using wine will prove more successful.

Comment: Well, currently, I'm trying to run a program that loads a website into a program so that I don't have to use the browser to use the websites content. The website incidentally happens to use flash player. My big problem is not having a non-executable version of the program, if one is even possible.

Comment: I see.  I'll get right on that.  In the meantime, please see the paragraph I added at the bottom of my current answer.

Comment: As requested I've added a section to my answer regarding standalone flash player.  I'm guessing that's what you are asking for.  "a non executable version of the program" is rather like an oxymoron; just because a file doesn't end in exe, does not mean it is not executable, it just means it's not made for dos/windows.

Comment: How about installing Adobe Flash Player for Windows under WINE as suggested in the Accepted Answer here? : http://askubuntu.com/questions/104877/how-do-i-install-flash-in-to-firefox-running-with-wine

Comment: I'm not saying that windows programs run under Ubuntu WINE don't work.  If I believed that, I wouldn't count myself an Ubuntu WINE expert.  I have a very good idea of what works and what doesn't.  One thing that doesn't tend to work is automated exchanges between programs made for Ubuntu and programs made for windows, and it rather sounds like that's what you are expecting, and I expect you will be disappointed.  In your most recent comment you wrote, "as suggested in the Accepted here?".  I don't claim to be able to guess what an "accepted here" is.

Comment: I meant the "Accepted Answer" (http://askubuntu.com/a/106240/47343) to the question I've linked, or even another answer there (http://askubuntu.com/a/223981/47343) might perhaps be helpful to this end, and I'm not claiming to be an expert in any of the areas involved here ;-)